# Terraform, Azure and AKS, can I create a route table to a NAT GW in a peered vnet?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a Hub & Spoke network with an AKS in one spoke:

```
                            [NAT GW]
[Hub Vnet]  <--peering--> [Spoke Vnet]
                             [AKS]
```

Maybe over-engineering here, but I would like to move the NAT Gateway to the hub:

```
 [NAT GW]
[Hub Vnet]  <--peering--> [Spoke Vnet]
                             [AKS]
```

Is it possible to get the Spoke Vnet, or rather the routing table for AKS, to route 0.0.0.0/0-traffic to the hub GW?
I only manage to make it work through Terraform as in the first sketch.
The VNet and NAT config with peering is working fine, what I don't seem to get working is the `network_profile` setup in AKS.

Comment: Please provide TF that you wrote for that problem, and explain why it doesn't work. Any errros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can totally do this.
The docs are ok : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress-outboundtype#outbound-type-of-userdefinedrouting

You simply need to specify a different outboundType in the network profile.
When you do this, it will check to **make sure that a UDR is in place** on the subnet, so you really need to make sure all of the config is sequenced correctly.

[image]